# Google storage in .NET using a Google Cloud Platform service account and key file

Tags: c#, .net, f#, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage

How does one establish the oauth-2 connection to Google storage in .NET using a Google Cloud Platform service account and key file? The available examples and documentation do not address service accounts, and the APIs are confusing and seem to frequently change, making the existing documentation questionable. A working code example would be best, including the significant API namespaces and versions.

Comment: have you looked at  DotNetOpenAuth/? https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Security-scenarios

Comment: @weismat I'll take a look. For now I'm solving my core task in a different way. Google has no incentive to make .NET development easy.

Answer (score 1):

The code sample in the [Cloud Storage JSON API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-dotnet-samples) only covers using Application Default credentials unfortunately, after having set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to the downloaded JSON key.

However there is a sample in the [documentation for the Google API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service-account) for using a Service Account with an exported P12 key, which you can use to adapt the CreateStorageClient() method given in the Cloud Storage docs:

```
public StorageService CreateStorageClient()
{
  String serviceAccountEmail = "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_HERE";
  var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

  ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
      Scopes = new[] { StorageService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

  var serviceInitializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
  {
    ApplicationName = "Storage Sample",
    HttpClientInitializer = credential
  };

  return new StorageService(serviceInitializer);
}
```

The same method using a JSON key directly, based on the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.10.0/namespaceGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2):

```
public StorageService CreateStorageClient()
{
  GoogleCredential credential;
  using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
      .CreateScoped(StorageService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl);
  }

  var serviceInitializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
  {
    ApplicationName = "Storage Sample",
    HttpClientInitializer = credential
  };

  return new StorageService(serviceInitializer);
}
```

Note that I haven't tested these as I don't currently have a .NET dev environment set up, but it should give a general idea of how it works. I'll request an update to the Cloud Storage docs to add an example which uses a JSON key.

Comment: Since we developed a workaround to our underlying issue it may be some time before I can verify this solution.